# Google Colab GPU environment establish

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run my deep learning code in Google Colab, I have installed cuda10.0.130 and cudnn7.6.4 for tensorflow 1.14.0, but the result of `tf.test.is_gpu_available()` is still false, I don't know what can I do now, can somebody give me some instructions? Here is the output of `!sudo lsb_release -a`  and   `!nvidia-smi`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Supported and Tested configurations for GPU versions are given here in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu)

Supported Version  for Cuda 10.1  and Cudnn 7.6 will be tensorflow_gpu-2.3.0
Also for TF 1.X versions CPU and GPU support are different

So you should do

```
!pip install tensorflow_gpu==1.14.0
```

for using GPU version of Tensorflow

Ref- https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#older_versions_of_tensorflow